# How to give different column data types at the constructor of dataframe of Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I try to create a dataframe in which includes integer values at the first column and string values at the second column. How can I do it in pandas? From its introductory documentation, I could not find such an example. It gives one dtype for all the columns.

For example;

```
ColumnA ColumnB
1         aba
2         bba
3         dce
7         fge
5         efd
12        bla
11        blq
type=int  type=str
```

So as you can see first column "ColumnA" is in the type of integer and 2nd column "ColumnB"
is string. How can I create a data frame with the given datatypes as such?

Comment: Sorry can you explain better? You can pass the dtypes as a dict to the DataFrame constructor, otherwise the types can be deduced

Comment: See the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html#pandas.DataFrame and http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#dataframe for example the following is able to deduce the dtypes fine `df = pd.DataFrame({'num':range(2), 'str':['hello', 'pandas']})`

Comment: Note that pandas has no separate `str` type column, they end up being `object` type columns.